# Can a CFT have multiple primary operators with same scaling dimension and/or spin?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

In CFT ($d>2$), 2-point functions (between two scalar primary operators, for example) vanish unless the operators have same scaling dimension. This leads me to wonder whether a CFT can have two operators with same scaling dimension. Extending to the possibility of spin-ful primaries, is it possible that they have same spin and/or scaling dimension?

Another way to phrase the question is whether it is possible to have degeneracies in the spectrum of primary states (in any suitable quantization, e.g. radial quantization).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes: in general, it is possible to have operators sharing the same scaling dimension and spin.

However, this is a very peculiar situation, and in practice it only happens when there is some kind of symmetry in the system. For instance:

- The linear sigma model in $d = 2$ dimensions (see the other answer by Prof. Legolasov); in this case the symmetry is Lorentz symmetry.
- The $O(N)$ models in $d = 3$ dimensions, in which the "fundamental" field is a $N$-component vector, i.e. there are $N$ scalar operators sharing the same scaling dimension. The simplest example in this family is the $O(2)$ model, sometimes also called XY-model, which describes the critical point of superfluid helium.

In most cases, it is possible to choose your basis of primary operators so that the 2-point functions are diagonal, in the sense that distinct operators have a vanishing 2-point functions. This is why most of the time in CFT we are assuming that 2-point functions only involve identical operators.

But this is in fact not always possible: there are *logarithmic CFTs*, a special type of non-unitary CFT (discussed in $d > 2$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03959)), in which you can have 2-point functions that mix distinct operators with the same scaling dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please comment on whether unitarity of the theory is necessary and/or sufficient for making the distinct operators orthogonal?

Comment: Since the 2-point function of primary operators are essentially norms of states, unitarity is sufficient, I believe. But it is certainly not necessary: you could imagine a non-unitary theory with a global symmetry.

Comment: I understand your comment on the sufficiency part. But for the "necessary" part, are you saying that for a non-unitary theory with global symmetry, it's possible to choose orthogonal operators? Is this generally true, or is there an example you're thinking of?

Comment: Yes, I meant for a non-unitary theory you can have either: (1) operators that are not diagonalizable, as in the logarithmic CFT paper I referenced in the answer; or (2) diagonalizable operators, and yet the theory is non-unitary, for instance if you have several negative-norm operators (I think that the O(N) models in non-integer dimensions are of this type, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00013).

Answer (score 6):

Simplest example that comes to mind: a linear sigma model (the kind you encounter in bosonic string theory). Its central charge $c$ is a positive integer and there are $c$ different primaries $\partial X^{\mu}$ ($\mu$ ranging from $0$ to $c-1$). These primaries are different fields, but they all have conformal weights of $(1, 0)$ hence the same scaling dimension and the same spin.

Comment: +1 One could also take several products of the same theory.

Comment: @RyanThorngren did you mean direct sums of Vir representations with the same value of $c$?

Comment: Just take n copies of your favorite theory. It has a bunch of degeneracies, splitting in reps of the permutation group.

Comment: @RyanThorngren well the central charge of the resulting theory will be $n$ times the central charge of your original theory, so there is a possibility of shenanigans with the resulting Vir module etc., but I suppose it isn't relevant to show OP's point...

Comment: This is in $d=2$, right? Is there an example for $d>2$?

Comment: @ArkyaChatterjee what Ryan said

Comment: @RyanThorngren This sounds like a global flavor symmetry. Is that a correct interpretation of your example?

Comment: @ArkyaChatterjee, I think it is highly unlikely that you will find examples of such degeneracies which are not linked to a symmetry of some sort. Perhaps in some solvable examples, where the scaling dimensions are forced to lie in a discrete set. This is not to say it is provably impossible.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk That was also my hunch, and I was wondering whether there are necessary/sufficient conditions regarding this. If there are degeneracies, we usually associate them with some underlying symmetry such as the dynamical SU(N) symmetry in higher dimensional SHO. That is unless this is an "accidental" degeneracy, which is a term I've seen used in band theory for 3d crystalline solids, for example.